# R Software plot 3D Quantum orbital (spherical harmonics)

Tags: r

Using surf3D or persp3D in R i'm trying to reproduce the following plot function of Maple:

```
>plot3d(Re(sqrt(15/(8*Pi))*(sin(theta)*cos(theta)*exp(I*phi)))^2,phi=0..2*Pi,theta=0..Pi,coords=spherical,scaling=constrained,style=patchcontour,numpoints=5000,axes=frame)
```

To get something similar (or better) than the plot visible below:

[image]

Does anyone have a quick answer before i start to investigate personally on the subject by myself?

Thx in advance for your help.

Comment: *"Does anyone have a quick answer before i start to investigate personally on the subject by myself"* You should *always* investigate personally before posting here (or anywhere else on SE). SO is not a code writing/tutorial service, and it is always appreciated if you demonstrate that you've spent a considerable amount of time solving the issue youself prior to posting here.

Comment: You're right but i tried already 3 hours before asking the question. After 6 hours more of investigation i get i think the solution:

Answer (score 0):

Here is i think a piece (or the complete?) of the solution (maybe we can do better and simpler, including for example iso-curves and the colors that should be red as far we are from the center and not just on the vertical axis z):

```
library("plot3D")
theta<-seq(from = 0, to = pi, by = pi/320)
phi<-seq(from = 0, to = 2*pi, by = pi/160)

m<-length(phi); n=length(theta)
Phi<-matrix(rep(phi,each=n),nrow=n)
Theta<-matrix(rep(theta,m),nrow=n)


r = Re(1/2*sqrt(15/(2*pi))*exp(-1i*Phi)*sin(theta)*cos(Theta))
x = r*cos(Phi)
y = r*sin(Phi)
z = r*cos(Theta)

surf3D(x, y, z,colkey=TRUE,box=TRUE,bty="b2",main="A Spherical Harmonic")
```

The result gives:

[image]